# how to read superscripts from excel with out changing format into r-markdown pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to display superscript in my pdf using r-markdown. How can i display superscripts as superscripts without changing. i'm trying to display this in latex chunk

[image]

```
df<- read_excel("../df.xlsx",sheet = 'sheet1' )

`r df$text`
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following excel file `superscript.xlsx`

[image]

```
library(tidyxl)
library(tidyverse)

# Read in cells from excel
cells <- tidyxl::xlsx_cells("./data/superscript.xlsx")
# Get formatting
final <- cells %>%
  # Keep relevant columns
  dplyr::select(sheet, address, character, format = character_formatted) %>%
  # Spread cells with mixed formatting over over multiple rows
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(format), names_sep = "_")
```

Now you can see what p[art of the text is formatted (with superscript),
use this info in your markdown..

[image]

As you canb see above, from the content of cell A1, the `2`-part of `test2` is formatted with superscript.

Comment: I didn't get it.can you please tell how exactly it works or  how to use that test^2. even i have multiple rows and superscripts in same cell forrmat_vertAlign shows me NA

Answer (score 0):

from what i look from your code this may help

add this piece of code in excel file where ever superscript is required

```
$\textsuperscript{1}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution since you are using RMarkdown is to intermix HTML and utilize the `<sub>` superscript tag. Just an idea if you can avoid latex.

For latex, though, I would just manually adjust the value in your latex:

i.e. change `seller(1)` to `seller^{(1)}`

LaTeX handles superscripted superscripts and all of that stuff in a natural way. It even does the right thing when something has both a subscript and a superscript.

With @Wimpel 's answer, you can automate the process by pre-determining which values in the excel cells had superscripts at least. Still, I don't see how an XML-based Excel read would know how to convert to latex through markdown automatically.